# java: illegal forward reference for both static ans instance variable

Tags: java, initialization

I am having the following problem:

```
public class IntitializeTest {

    static {
        System.out.println("Static Initializer");
        i = 1;
        k = 2;
        System.out.println(i+" "+k) // illegal forward reference;
    }
    static int i;
    static int k;

    {
        System.out.println("Instance Initializer");
        thisString = "   empty    ";
        b = 0;
        System.out.println(thisString+b)  // illegal forward reference;
    }
    String thisString;
    int b;
}
```

what would be the order of initialization here? for Eg: I am able to initialize before declaring the variable "b", but not able to print it because of the error.
Java docs mentions the left-hand side rule, How does this apply here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Declare the variables before initialisers

Comment: The restriction in JLS 8.3.3 basically says: you may assign some value to a field before the declaration of the field (i.e. this is allowed `i = 1;` because it appears on the left hand side of an assignment operation), but you may not read the value of the value before the declaration of the field (i.e. this `System.out.println(i+" "+k);` is not allowed because it reads the values of i and k)